# Android: Package.getPackages() returns null

Tags: java, android

How to get a list of all java class packages in Android. I have tried with `Package.getPackages()` method but its returning `null`.

```
Package[] packages = Package.getPackages()  // 'Packages' is null
```

Comment: Show some code (and fix the missing word in your question,) please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a list of all installed app packages, or something along those lines, in which case, I would visit [This link](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/) He does a wonderful job at giving a step-by-step answer as to what you need to do to make this happen.

Comment: Package.getPackages() returns classes known to the class loader, so if that's the method he's using he's not looking for installed apps.  He's looking for known classes in this application.  (or he's using the wrong method)

Comment: @Dale Wilson you're right, after re-reading the sentence it almost seems like he wants the to list all of the given packages for a certain android app (not necessarily his own)? hmm...

Comment: Thanks WillBD and Dale Wilson for your time, actually I am looking for classes known to the class loader. 

Is there any way through which I can get java package names available in a android app